# Does these terms consider the same: Voltage, electric potential, and potential difference?

Tags: physics, terminology

What are the differences between these terms? Are they considered the same?

Comment: and also electric potential difference

Comment: What did google tell you?

Comment: I did not find any satisfactory answer

Answer (score 1):

*Voltage* and *electrostatic potential difference* are the same thing, only using the word *voltage* specifies that you will be measuring the potential difference in units of volts.

*Electrostatic potential* is in principle a scalar field that exists at all points in space (assuming a quasi-static system). However we can't directly measure potential because its value may be changed by an arbitrary offset without changing any physically observable behavior of a system. Thus we only measure differences in the potential between two points, giving us the *potential difference*.